# Django Union Query from multiple databases and Output the result in the specific format

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

Since I am new to django, I know how to query a single model in Django but I need to query multiple models at the same time.

I need to develop a UNION query in Django with 3 models namely WebQuery,WebReply and BusinessOwners and the output should be of the form below.

```
{
    "(#conversation_id#)_(#b_id#)": {
        "from": "(#user_id)",
        "email": "(#user_email)",
        "date_time": "#get from db",
        "query": "are you open ?",
        "from_r_id": "(#representative_id)",
        "from_r_name": "(#rep_name)",
        "business_registered": "FALSE"
        "to_business_name": "CCD saket",
        "chat": [{
            "direction": 1,
            "text": "yes sir",
            "date_time": "424 577"
        }, {
            "direction": 0,
            "text": "ok",
            "date_time": "424 577"
        }]
    },
```

Here is my models.py file.

```
class Businessowners(models.Model):
    b_id = models.IntegerField()
    userid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='UserID')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=150L)
    b_name = models.CharField(max_length=100L)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'businessowners'

class Users(models.Model):
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20L)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'

class WebQuery(models.Model):
    query_id = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    conversation_id = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    u_id = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    u_query = models.CharField(max_length=500L)
    sent_to = models.CharField(max_length=500L)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    is_reply = models.IntegerField()
    is_responded = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'web_query'

class WebReply(models.Model):
    reply_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    query_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    conversation_id = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    b_id = models.CharField(max_length=20L)
    u_query = models.CharField(max_length=500L)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=20L)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'web_reply'
```

Comment: If you are generating JSON, you probably want to take a look at the Python Rest Framework and their serialization classes.

Comment: No. I'm not. Any further assistance please. Thanks.

Comment: Your sample for the desired output looks like valid JSON to me.

Comment: What if I just want to query those 3 models, apply some loops in it thereby getting the desired O/P.?

Comment: what I want to know is how to query 3 models simultaneously, ie , how to apply union query in those 3 models?

Comment: In order to retrieve related models, the best way is using explicit relationships (models.ForeignKey and/or models.ManyToMany).

Comment: Can you please be a little more descriptive? Thanks

Comment: I'm commenting and not answering because I cant afford to write a potentially long answer right now. See [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

Comment: Nevermind. I'll wait for your answer. Just answer when you get free. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This question is so similar to another which has recently been asked that I recommend you taking a look at [Django Union Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653743/django-union-query/17653984#17653984).

Basically the way forwards would be to use SQL views if all the sources can be gathered. Then query that view.